# Phalcon Dev Tools - Database migrations

Tags: php, phalcon

I would like to know if phalcon php has a tool to create and apply migrations such as django has. I django I create my models and to create the migrations script I just have to type this command: `python manage.py makemigrations app_name` . And to apply migrations to my project: `python manage.py migrate app_name`

I would like to know if there is something with the same functinality on phalcon php. I have the phalcon dev tools 2.0.13 and I've been reading about the migration command but as far as I've read I couldn't find such functionality (or I'm not understanding).

Can you help me?
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found:

`phalcon migration generate` to create the migration files
`phalcon migration run` to apply the migration files to the database

Tips: create a `.phalcon` directory in the root of your project if you get this error message: `Error: This command should be invoked inside a Phalcon project directory`.

And in you config file set `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` if you get this error: `ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory`